# Assign string to UITextView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitextview

I am trying to load text into a textview. This seems simple enough:

```
box.text = @"hello";
NSLog(@"Box.text contains: %@", box.text);
```

The problem is that this NSLog just keeps printing null. 
(I have IBOutlet UITextView *box declared.) I imagine that since box.text is null, that's why nothing is actually showing up in the UITextView either.

Anyone know what's going wrong?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Which method are you putting these two lines of code in?

Comment: Oh wow THANK YOU SO MUCH! I was putting it in the init of my view controller. Just moved it to viewDidLoad and it's all good. Dumb mistake, thanks a lot for the answer. I probably would have gone in circles for a while longer until I realized this simple thing.

Comment: @Scott: I'd say you should turn that into an answer and reap some rep!

Comment: Yeah, I went ahead and deleted my answer since it didn't *actually* solve the problem; go ahead and post yours @Scott Forbes. :)

Comment: I'll turn it into an actual answer for posterity's sake.  :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're calling `box.text` from your controller's `init` method, your IBOutlet hasn't been loaded from the nib file yet – so `box` is still pointing to nil, and the text assignment is going nowhere. You'll need to wait until `viewDidLoad` or later to successfully access the properties of your IBOutlet.